# Replace line break

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

In Fluid Template and tx_news, I need to replace line breaks with "\n" for passing into JavaScript function.

If a JavaScript string contains line break, console will print "Unexpected token."

```
<a onclick="doSomething('{newsItem.bodytext}');">Click me</a>
```

How can you replace line breaks with "\n" in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your own ViewHelper and use it like this:

```
{namespace ns=Vendor\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers}

<a onclick="doSomething('{newsItem.bodytext -> ns:viewhelperName()}');">Click me</a>
```

More infos here: [Developing a custom ViewHelper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html)

Answer (score 4):

AS urbantrout already wrote: you can write an own viewhelper in PHP.

But you also can use a TypoScript-Viewhelper:

```
<a onclick="doSomething('{newsItem.bodytext -> f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: \'lib.nlReplace\')}');">Click me</a>
```

(as you are in a string you need to escape the inner ')
and some TypoScript like

```
lib.nlReplace = TEXT
lib.nlReplace {
    current = 1
    stdWrap.replacement {
        1 {
            search = #\n#
            replace = \\n
            useRegExp = 1
        }
    }
}
```